# How to create custom shortcuts for DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, datagridview

I'm trying to create a shortcut (CTRL+J) in a `DataGridView` control in a Windows form.  The shortcut should simply do exactly what the down arrow does (i.e., in most cases, change the selection to the next item).

I am trying to handle CTRL+J by overriding the form's `FormKeyDown` event and using `SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}")` if `FormKeyDown` receives the J key and Ctrl as a modifier.

However, when I send the `{DOWN}` key, it acts like Ctrl+Down since the user is still holding the CTRL key!

How can I create the custom shortcut so that it has exactly the same behavior as a shortcut the `DataGridView` already supports?

Comment: Why not create a single method that both `Ctrl+j` and `down` event handlers call?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid relying on mimicking user input with `SendKeys` and instead use the correct API for programmatic selection available on `DataGridView` class. You can check the programmatic selection section on the following page:

[Selection Modes in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6w9028.aspx)

When implementing the code for programmatic selection you need to take in consideration the  `SelectionMode` configured for your data grid view.

---

Alternatively you can subclass from `DataGridView` and implement your custom shortcuts so that they redirect to the existing ones. Example:

```
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.J))
        {
            this.ProcessDownKey(Keys.Down);

            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```